# Version Controlling and Release Logs Maintaining Mechanism for Oracle

Tags: database, version-control, oracle10g, release-management, oracleforms

We have an application developed over Oracle 10 G (DS) forms connected with the Oracle Database in which time by time there are changes we need to make in scripts and procedures defined.

Task assigned to our group is to find out possible Version Controlling and Release Logs Maintaining Mechanism that could record every change made and release finalized in database.

I want a word of suggestion from all the experienced people out here, what could be the best possible solution of our problem, ideally a single solution or multiple ones.

*(I am not very Oracle Form-Literate, so apologizes if I sounded confusing)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Database_CI.aspx) and [this](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html).

The first link is about .Net projects, but gives you concrete examples for how to set up your development processes; the second link is a general approach from Martin Fowler, who is a bit of an authority on software development.

The basics are that you have to script/automate as much of the deployment lifecycle as possible, and version everything.

I don't know much about Oracle Forms, but as far as I know, this approach should work.